# Python unindent error only in python REPL even with correct # of spaces (and no tabs)

Tags: python, indentation

In the following code block

```
def classify0(inx, ds, ls, k):
  sdindices = dist.argsort()
  clcount = {}
  for i in range(k):
    vlab = ls[sdindices[i]]
    clcount[vlab] = clcount.get(vlab,0)+1
  sclcount = sorted(clcount.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
  # Previous lines gives: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
  return sclcount[0][0]
```

As shown in the comment, the line starting with

```
sclcount = "
```

gives the indention error.  Now I have checked all the 'usual suspects': there are no tabs and the correct # of spaces.

Also, i am using PyCharm (/intellij) and no warnings/syntax errors . Only in the python shell..

Comment: All of the indents are using 2 spaces

Comment: @AvinashRaj, 4 spaces are recommended, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: The code you posted works for me. Can you post the code in the for loop?

Comment: @synonym ok. it does not matter though - i get same error.  but you asked so I will

Comment: You get the same error even if you type in exactly as you posted here?

Comment: @syntonym  yes correct

Comment: Does it also happen if you save it as a file and execute it?

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question, now that you've solved the problem, so that it shows as answered in the list.

Comment: A problem with associating this question/closing it is that .. how is a developer supposed to know to search for `%cpaste` unless they're already well familiar with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like %cpaste (or %paste) in ipython fixes the issue.